# Can't connect to Internet

Tags: wireless-networking

I have recently acquired a Dell XPS M1330 laptop. I haven't come across any need to enter a password as yet to use the laptop but fear that if I may need to at some point in the future, have no knowledge of what that might be from the previous owner or any way of finding out. Is there a way I can reset the password without knowing what the previous one was. Also having attempted to go onto the Internet went to diagnose problems when it would not connect. I then went into the connection option when you right click on the Internet explorer icon and selecting the households wireless provider. I followed all the steps to connect this provider using the required password. I then attempted to open Internet explorer again and it will still not open saying it might be conection probs/the website/or typing error although when looking at the connection it says their is one and the signal is a full bar. Please advise how I can connect the laptop to the Internet.
Regards
Laura

Comment: If you got a laptop with an OS from a person you do not explicitly trust (and that includes his or her safety record while surfing) then the first thing you want to do is to reimage the system. That will also erase any old password. Dell laptop usually come with a restore image and or a OS DVD.

Answer (score 3):

Do a clean install on windows before anything, to get rid of this other persons garbage and settings.  After this, update Windows.  Then, get the password for a wireless network that you own or trust and type that in when attempting to connect and go from there.